# Hibernate Native Query bad Performance and struggling to convert to JQPL

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I wrote this SQL Query and using it as a native query in hibernate.

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT DISTINCT tp.* FROM TWITTER_POST AS tp " +
                "JOIN TWITTER_LIST AS tl " +
                    "ON tl.owner_id = ?1 " +
                "JOIN REL_TWITTER_LIST__ACCOUNTS_TRACKED_BY_LIST AS atbl " +
                    "ON tl.id = atbl.twitter_list_id " +
                "JOIN TWITTER_ACCOUNT AS ta " +
                    "ON ta.id = atbl.accounts_tracked_by_list_id " +
                "LEFT OUTER JOIN REL_TWITTER_POST__TWITTER_USERS_HIDING_POST uhp " +
                    "ON tp.id = uhp.twitter_post_id " +
                    "AND uhp.TWITTER_USERS_HIDING_POST_ID = ?1 " +
                "WHERE uhp.twitter_post_id is NULL AND ta.id = tp.author_id",
        countQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT count(tp.*) FROM TWITTER_POST AS tp " +
                     "JOIN TWITTER_LIST AS tl " +
                        "ON tl.owner_id = ?1 " +
                     "JOIN REL_TWITTER_LIST__ACCOUNTS_TRACKED_BY_LIST AS atbl " +
                        "ON tl.id = atbl.twitter_list_id " +
                     "JOIN TWITTER_ACCOUNT AS ta " +
                        "ON ta.id = atbl.accounts_tracked_by_list_id " +
                     "LEFT OUTER JOIN REL_TWITTER_POST__TWITTER_USERS_HIDING_POST uhp " +
                        "ON tp.id = uhp.twitter_post_id " +
                        "AND uhp.TWITTER_USERS_HIDING_POST_ID = ?1 " +
                     "WHERE uhp.twitter_post_id is NULL AND ta.id = tp.author_id",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    Page<TwitterPost> findAllNonHiddenForListsFromTwitterAccountId(Long twitterAccountId, Pageable pageable);
```

I noticed that the query executes very slowly when I'm running it through hibernate as opposed to a SQL tool. I assumed it was because I am using a native query as opposed to JQPL, which (from what I read) immediately does caching and pagination without requiring a definition for "count". Trying to convert it to JQPL failed, because I cannot find a good tutorial for more complicated queries on JQPL across join tables.

```
@Query(
    value = "SELECT DISTINCT twitterPost " +
            "FROM TwitterPost twitterPost " +
            "JOIN TwitterList twitterList " +
                "ON twitterList.owner.id = ?1 " +
            "JOIN TwitterAccount tweetAuthorFromList " +
                "ON tweetAuthorFromList IN twitterList.accountsTrackedByLists " +
            "WHERE twitterPost.author = tweetAuthorFromList " +
                "AND twitterList.owner NOT IN twitterPost.twitterUsersHidingPosts"
)
Page<TwitterPost> findAllNonHiddenPostsFromListsForTwitterAccountId(Long twitterAccountId, Pageable pageable);
```

Apparently my Syntax is off

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare
> statement

but the compiler only shows me problems with the generated SQL, not the JQPL so I'm left in the dark.

Also checked for typical bad performance culprits i.e. eager fetching of entities which I set to lazy everywhere.

Any help regarding whether my performance problem assumptions are correct, or converting the query, are highly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume that you return a lot of data from the query. How many records do you get back?

Comment: Some 240 rows maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things that are wrong here:

- Using SELECT DISTINCT with JOIN indicates that you should have used a Semi Join instead.
- The `ON tl.owner_id = ?1` is done for filtering, not for the projection, hence you are better off doing an EXISTS query.
- Assuming why the query runs slow instead of profiling it. The reason why it runs faster in the DB tool is that DB tools usually truncate the result set while Spring Data consumes the entire result set. Or, if you run `EXPLAIN`, the output might come from the Optimizer without even running the query.

So, here's what you can do:

1. Use Semi Joins instead of Joins for filtering.
2. Use `Blaze Persistence` to write better entity queries dynamically.
3. Configure Statement Caching at the JDBC Driver level.
4. Use the slow query log to log the execution plan when the query is slower than N seconds.

Comment: Hero Vlad is always to the rescue when it comes to Hibernate questions xD

Comment: Haha he is indeed...may I ask regarding JPQL vs SQL Native Query - is there a performance difference?

Comment: JPQL is for fetching entities that you plan to modify. That's it. Most often, people use it as a replacement for SQL, which is not what Hibernate devs wanted you to do. If Hibernate devs didn't want you to use SQL when you don't want to fetch entities (analytics, projections, recursive queries), then why there's a `createNativeQuery` method?